# How to clean excess wax out of my ear

Tags: personal-care

Similar to [this question](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/6726/how-to-clean-my-ear-canal-with-something-more-reusable-than-a-cotton-swab) but I'm actually wanting to remove wax from the inside of my ear.

The doctor told me I should put drops of oil in my ear to soften the wax before they can clean it.
What is the best way to get a couple of drops of oil into my ear without making a mess? Preferably with products anyone has at home.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it is fairly easy, just dip a finger in oil, tap out excess oil and touch the earhole with oiled finger. that much oil is sufficient to ease out the wax. do not try to force the wax out. it will just move out.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, will give it a go and then I'll accept the answer if it works :)

Answer (score 2):

Here where I live, liquid paraffin (aka paraffin oil) comes at pharmacies in small (100ml) plastic bottles. They have small neck, so the oil drips as you squeeze the bottle. That's two birds with one stone, as paraffin also is the oil you should be putting in your ear in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

My husband's ears produce a lot of wax and, as told by his doctor, he adds a couple of olive oil drops in his ears once a week. I usually perform the task **with a teaspoon** (well clean). We know the drop is inside because he can feel it. I do mess up from time to time, it is not a problem, just clean it with a tissue. He is able to add the oil drops with the teaspoon by himself if I am not at home, just practice.
Good luck, you are not alone.

Answer (score 1):

I've had good success with [Debrox](http://smile.amazon.com/Debrox-Earwax-Removal-Drops-Fluid/dp/B00ANL4Z4I/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1445906661&sr=8-1&keywords=debrox%20%22Debrox%22.%20%20It's%20only%20$5.).  It's only $5.

Answer (score 1):

Hydrogen Peroxide is the active ingredient in OTC ear wax removal solutions. You will fill it "fizzing" but don't worry that's what it's supposed to do. Just keep your head to the side so the H2O2 has time to sit in your ear for a minute or two to break up the wax.

P.S.   hydrogen peroxide is just water with an extra Oxygen molecule lightly attached

Comment: Wikipedia on Hydrogen peroxide: Hydrogen peroxide is often described as being “water but with one more oxygen atom”, a description which can give the incorrect impression that there is a great deal of similarity between the two compounds.  Pure hydrogen peroxide will explode if heated to boiling, will cause serious contact burns to the skin and can set materials alight on contact. For these reasons it is usually handled as a dilute solution (household grades are typically 3-6%).

Comment: I wouldn't feel safe putting that stuff on my eardrum - even if they weren't perforated. "contact burns to the skin".. so what about a thin membrane of skin?!

Comment: My son's doctor used hydrogen peroxide to soften some earwax buildup and irrigated his ear with warm water. Flushed everything right out.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use a q-tip and dip it into oil, then reach it to your earhole. The amount of oil can be adjusted based on how much of the q-tip you dip in oil and how you place the q-tip inside/at opening of your earhole.

Comment: Bad idea!  Never stick anything inside your ear.  You risk breaking your eardrum.

Comment: With a Q-tip you risk pushing the wax further into your ear canal.

Comment: Of course I wouldn't suggest sticking it far into the ear. I believe we all have a common sense to what extent we should do stuff with our body. For example, if we are getting warm around camp fire, we all know not to get too close to burn ourselves or catch ourselves on fire.

Comment: You're right about common sense, but some people have none. So you should never advise anybody to stick something into their ear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Syringe** without needle. Fill syringe with water and ask someone to spray into ear 25-30 times. (Don't let water stay inside your ear for long) 
Remove dirt with cotton if comes out.

Comment: Make sure not to use too much pressure. You want to gently rinse the ear, not blast your eardrum out. Also, use hand-warm water to help soften the wax.

Comment: Insure that the water is warm to the person who is having their ear flushed, as if it isn't, it will harden the ear wax. I once had a nurse try to flush my ear with water that was warm to her, but cold to me.